# SAP DBTech JDBC: [305]: single-row query returns more than one row

Tags: jdbc, hana

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN FLAG1 = 'FALSE' AND FLAG2 = 'FALSE' THEN '99Z' 
                ELSE (CASE WHEN FLAG1 = 'FALSE' THEN TGK2 ELSE TGK1 END) END
FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN FLAG1 = 'FALSE' THEN '99Z' ELSE 'X'||CAMPO28||'_'||'Y'||CAMPO29 END AS TGK1,
                CASE WHEN FLAG2 = 'FALSE' THEN '99Z' ELSE (CASE WHEN CAMPO15 IS NULL THEN '99Z' ELSE CAMPO15 END) END AS TGK2, 
                FLAG1,FLAG2
FROM
(SELECT CASE 
           WHEN CAMPO1 IN (
             SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(COD_CONTO,7) 
                 FROM CONTO_GERARCHIA_ABBI 
                 WHERE COD_CONTO_GERARCHIA = 'H14' 
                   AND (COD_CONTO LIKE '3%' OR COD_CONTO LIKE '4%') 
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(COD_CONTO,10) 
                 FROM CONTO_GERARCHIA_ABBI 
                 WHERE COD_CONTO_GERARCHIA = 'H14' AND (COD_CONTO LIKE '1%' OR COD_CONTO LIKE '2%'))
           AND CAMPO27 = 'ZZ' THEN CAMPO1 ELSE 'FALSE' END AS FLAG1,
        CASE WHEN CAMPO1 IN (
                    SELECT LEFT(COD_CONTO,7) 
                    FROM CONTO_GERARCHIA_ABBI 
                    WHERE COD_CONTO_GERARCHIA = 'H10' )
               THEN CAMPO1 ELSE 'FALSE' END AS FLAG2, 
        CAMPO15, CAMPO28, CAMPO29, CAMPO1
     FROM MAP_DATI_ACQUISITI 
     WHERE 1=1 AND COD_MAPPATURA = '100' AND COD_IMPORT = '010' 
) 
GROUP BY FLAG1, FLAG2, CAMPO15, CAMPO28, CAMPO29, CAMPO1  
)
```

The issue is that in SAP Hana I get the error [305].

Do you have any idea what would be the issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it is not clear whether you are operating on a SAP HANA On-Premise or on a SAP HANA Cloud System or which exact SAP HANA Revision are you operating on, respectively.

It could be an issue in the optimizer depending on the version. Maybe, for now you could just try a workaround by adding

```
WITH HINT (NO_USE_HEX_PLAN)
```

at the very end of your query.

Comment: Dear import_this,

Thank you so much for your answer. Actually is SAP Hana on cloud. I found an workaround to split the query in many transformations. I guess the variables that I use in the sub-query are not taken into account when I interrogate them.

Have a wonderful evening

Comment: Hi @Miriam, great to read that you have found a workaround. However, I do not understand why my answer had to be downgraded by -2 points?! I guess you did not even give it a try to run the orginal query that you posted here - for which you had actually requested help - with the respective HINT? If my suggestion worked then you would not have to rewrite your query. In addition, it probably would be an indication that we are dealing with an issue in your HANA version. In such a case hitting the update button would perhaps solve the problem, i.e., making rewriting or setting the HINT unnecessary.